# iframe AJAX request fails on first click, works flawlessly thereafter

Tags: ajax, iframe

The HTML calls "ajax_request('server_code.php','result_id')" onClick.  It fails the first time with this error:

*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null ajax_request ajax.js:35(anonymous function)*

But each subsequent call works perfectly. Why..?

**Download all files here: http://k.min.us/iejWmy.zip**

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <!-- ajax -->
    <script src='ajax.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
</head> 
    <body>
        <a id='test' href='#' onclick="ajax_request('php.php','show_result')">get ajax data</a>
        <div id='show_result'></div>
    <body>

</html>
```

**Javascript 'ajax.js'**

```
/****************************************************************************
Iframes based AJAX function.
@ url - server side script location
@ result_id - server side script output
****************************************************************************/
function ajax_request(url,result_id)
{   
    var ajax_iframe_id = 'ajax_iframe_loader';
    var ajax_iframe = document.getElementById(ajax_iframe_id);

    // create hidden iframe transfer buffer if it's not created already.
    if (ajax_iframe == null)
    {

        var element = document.createElement("iframe");
        element.setAttribute('src',url);
        element.setAttribute('id',ajax_iframe_id);
        document.body.appendChild(element);

        element.style.display='none';
        element.style.width='1';
        element.style.height='1';
        element.style.border='0';

        ajax_iframe = element;
    }

    // load server side page into iframe buffer
    ajax_iframe.src = url;

    // get the outputted result from inside our transfer div
    var iframe_inner_doc = ajax_iframe.contentDocument || ajax_iframe.contentWindow.document;

    // target AJAX data to transfer
    var content_to_transfer = iframe_inner_doc.getElementById('to_transfer').innerHTML;

    // paste result
    document.getElementById(result_id).innerHTML = content_to_transfer;
}
```

**PHP 'php.php'**

```
<html>
<body>
<div id='to_transfer'>random number via ajax is:<font size='15'><?=mt_rand(5, 15);?></font></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you set the iframe src, but no AJAX call. I suspect you're trying to access the contents of the iframe before it has any. Once you've loaded contents once, the to_transfer exists, but not the first time because you don't give it a chance to load the inner doc contents.

Comment: Appreciate the reply.  I'm trying hard to understand the order of events I need to follow to get this working.  Is this a timing issue ?  Should I wait for the server-side script to load before transferring it?